# iOS - Navigation controller swipe to return not working after orientation change

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I am building an app using a SplitViewController, and on the iPhone (where the detail VC is hidden), the 'slide to return' to the previous VC gesture recognizer works when the View controller appears, but once the orientation is changed (device is rotated), it no longer works. I know that the event is registered by setting the `navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer` 's delegate to self, and setting a breakpoint in the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` delegate function. So the event is registered, but the animation is not being triggered... any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Just for more information, the reason I need to set the nav controller's `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` delegate is because in this particular view controller, the navigation bar is hidden and replace with a custom one, and the only solution I was able to find is by re-assigning the delegate.. not sure if that's why this weird behaviour occurs

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, this was a mistake on my part, I was hiding the navigation bar in the `viewWillTransitionToSize` function, and for some reason the `interactivePopGestureDelegate` needs to specified everywhere that this is done, so I just had to re-set it and it now works.